# Why does $(AX + B)^{-1} = A \implies AX+B = A^{-1}$?

Tags: matrices

What rule or logic allows me to say that:$(AX + B)^{-1} = A \implies AX+B = A^{-1}$?

Comment: What is $(A^{-1})^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

It's because something having an inverse $\implies$ its inverse has an inverse. You can show that $(A^{-1})^{-1} = A$ for invertible functions/matrices,<s>you might wish to</s> you should prove it to yourself as an exercise.

Thus both sides of the equation are invertible (you can invoke [Leibniz's Rule](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Leibniz%27s_Law) if you like), and you can invert both sides, $a = b^{-1} \iff a^{-1} = (b^{-1})^{-1} = b$

Answer (score 0):

The rule is, that $C^{-1}=A$ implies $C=A^{-1}$ for matrices in $GL_n(K)$. It follows because $G=GL_n(K)$ is a group, and in any group we have $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$.